# JPA 2.0 CriteriaQuery on tables in @ManyToMany with JoinTable and Lazy Fetch

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have two entities in a @ManyToMany relationship like this:

> ```
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "USERS") 
> public class User implements EntityMetaModel, Serializable {
>
>   @Id
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
>   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
>   private Integer id; 
>
>   @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, length = 20)
>   private String username;
>
>   @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 32)
>   private String password;
>
>   @Column(name = "ENABLED")
>   private Boolean enabled;
>
>   @ManyToMany(
>       cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
>       fetch = (FetchType.LAZY)
>   )
>   @JoinTable(         
>       name = "USER_ROLES",
>       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USERID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
>       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ROLEID", referencedColumnName="ID")
>   )
>   @SequenceGenerator(
>       name = "sgIdUserRoles",
>       sequenceName = "SQ_ID_USER_ROLES"
>   ) 
>   @CollectionId(
>       columns = {@Column(name="ID")},
>       type = @Type(type="integer"), 
>       generator = "sgIdUserRoles"
>       )
>   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
>   private Collection<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
> }
>
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "ROLES")
> public class Role implements EntityMetaModel, Serializable {
>
>   @Id
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
>   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
>   private Integer id; 
>
>   @Column(name = "ROLENAME", unique = true, length = 50)
>   private String rolename;
>
>   @ManyToMany(
>       cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
>       fetch = (FetchType.LAZY)
>   )
>   @JoinTable(         
>       name = "USER_ROLES",
>       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ROLEID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
>       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USERID", referencedColumnName="ID")
>   )
>   @SequenceGenerator(
>       name = "sgIdUserRoles",
>       sequenceName = "SQ_ID_USER_ROLES"
>   ) 
>   @CollectionId(
>       columns = {@Column(name="ID")},
>       type = @Type(type="integer"), 
>       generator = "sgIdUserRoles"
>       )
>   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
>   private Collection<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
> }
> ```

I've created the metamodel:

> ```
> @StaticMetamodel(User.class)
> public class User_ {
>   public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, Integer> id;
>   public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, String> username;
>   public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, String> password;
>   public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, Boolean> enabled;        
>   public static volatile CollectionAttribute<User, Role> roles;
> }
>
> @StaticMetamodel(Role.class)
> public class Role_ {
>   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Role, Integer> id;
>   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Role, String> rolename;
>   public static volatile CollectionAttribute<Role, User> users;
> }
> ```

Class User has a Collection of Role. What I need to do from JPA2 CriteriaQuery is to find the Roles that havent an User given by id.
How can I do a CriteriaQuery like this?

```
select r.id, r.rolename 
from roles r 
where not exists 
(select 1 
from user_roles ur 
where ur.roleid = r.id 
and ur.userid = :userid)
```

Comment: please notify me, if I misunderstand the question, or the answer is not acceptable for you. I will clarify and fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

If a query is:

```
List<Role> roles = session.createQuery("select u.roles from User u left join fetch u.roles where u.id= :idParam").
     setParameter("idParam", param).
     asList();
```

the following criteria should work, as I remember:

```
List<Role> roles = session.
    createCriteria(Role.class).
    add(Restrictions.eq("users.id", param)).
    setFetchMode("users", FethchMode.EAGER).
    list();
```

Otherwise, you return a query with a non-entity structure, you may need a ResultTransformer.

Comment: The query should return the roles that the user does not have.
I need the code in JPA 2.0 mode (with CriteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder, Root, ...), not in Hibernate code.

Comment: In the question you write "find the Roles for an User given by id.", not "doesn't have". I'm working on it, but in this case it might be not slower, I havent use JPA CriteriaBuilder API directly. What are you trying? I found an `isNotMember` in `criteriabuilder`, it might work.

Comment: Azendh, sorry about the mistake.